# how do i know total number of specific nodes between root node and current node in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to count the total number of specific nodes between root node and current node.
for Example:

```
 <w:body> <!-- root Node -->
     <w:p/>
             <w:rect>
             <w:p>some text1</w:p>  
            </w:rect>
     <w:p/>
             <w:rect>
              <w:p>some text2</w:p>  
            </w:rect>

     <w:p/>
     <w:p/>
     <w:p/>
            <w:rect>
             <w:p>some text5</w:p>   <!-- This is current node now -->
            </w:rect>
     <w:p/>
     <w:p/>
     <w:p/>
     <w:p/>
</w:body>
```

This is my scenario.Here, Assume  some text is my current node.So, Now i want to get the parent::w:p of the current node **(Assume this node name as "targetNode")**. After that i want to calculate total number of the same level of w:p from root node to **targetNode**.

My wanted output is :5

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: @don Rody: Just assume it may contain child or nothing.I want to count total number of <w:p> from root node to parent <w:p> of the current node.That's it.

Comment: If 'some text5' is the text node you look at in your XML sample and you then navigate up to the parent `w:p` element that is itself inside of a `w:rect` element then I wonder 5 is the wanted output for the "total number of the same level of w:p" as that parent `w:p` element has no sibling elements at all. So what kind of level do you have in mind?

Comment: only <w:p>that are the immediate child of root node

Comment: @Martin Honnen:thank you very much for your time.Empo solved my issue...Plz refer his answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this single XPath expression:

```
 count(ancestor::w:p[1]/preceding-sibling::w:p + 1)
```

In this way we obtain the count of all preceding sibling **w:p** nodes of the first ancestor **w:p** + 1 (the first ancestor **w:p** itself).

Comment: :Sorry empo,it is not working under my scenario...it retreived 0

Comment: @Saravanan my fault, did not see that w:p is not immediate parent, check my answer now)